# Adding another team to xcode

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I want to submit my app with someone else's developer account in itunes connect. I want to export the ipa file with their team. I added their account to my xcode under Team dropdown in general tab. but I get the warning "No code signing identities found" I wanted to ask what are the steps to solve this issue.
Thanks very much

Comment: Please add a few screenshots to explain a bit more on this.

Comment: You'll need to have them export the certificate with the private key, and send that to you.

Comment: Thanks @AMayes , that was it, they needed to export the certificate+private key and all I needed to do was to import that.