# Adding another team in xcode

Tags: xcode

this question is not a duplicate of [Adding another team in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610740/adding-another-team-to-xcode)

or [How to upload ios app from xcode when invited to a developer team?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862585/how-to-upload-ios-app-from-xcode-when-invited-to-a-developer-team)

This second link is similar to my question but it was never solved.

So my humble question is: I want to add another (2nd) team in Xcode.
When I login to my Apple developer account through Safari, I can see my team and the (2nd) team I want to add in Xcode. But in Xcode I see only my team with no option to insert the (2nd) team that I see in my developer account.

I received an invitation and I've accepted it to join this team and my role is App Manager. So how to add it to Xcode, because I need to upload an app to their account.

Your help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: 2 years, no answer. NICE :D I am stuck with the same problem. Did you find a way Jessica?

Answer (score 0):

It is too late to answer but this might help someone stuck on this.

This is not an ideal solution but when I uninstall and re-installed Xcode again, it worked. My team then appears in Xcode. My lead did the same when he had the same issue more than a year ago.

My colleague had the same issue but fortunately for him, he was assigned a new email ID for some other reason. He then made an Apple ID from it and was added to the team first and later he installed Xcode.