# I don't see team in Xcode I'm member of

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, account

This question could be a duplicate of this one - [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160420/adding-another-team-in-xcode) but that question was asked 2 years ago and didn't get answered. Also, there were many questions related to this issues even before, but they are outdated now.

So, I got invited to an Apple Developer account with a role of Admin and I don't see that team in Xcode, that person, who invited me has individual account. Moreover, I'm a member of other developer accounts and I can see them and use. But that accounts are of organisation types.

If anyone faced same issue - how can I fix that?
Simply logging out of account in Xcode and relaunching/restarting Mac didn't help.

Comment: It's confusing, but I'm pretty sure that you can't be part of a team that isn't a team.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't explain clear enough. I mean a person has individual apple developer account, he invited me to his account, but I can upload apps to his account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that what the account holder actually did was this (as described by the [docs](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devad498718e)):

> Individuals enrolled in the Apple Developer Program can give up to 10 users access to their content in App Store Connect. All users receive access only to App Store Connect and are not considered part of the team in the Apple Developer Program.

That sounds like exactly your situation as you describe it.

Comment: Yes, that's explains everything, thanks. And in order to give me access to Apple Developer Program they have to change their account type to organisation, as stated in docs, thanks.